# Knockout JS - tabs in usercontrol not formatting

Tags: javascript, css, knockout.js, tabs

I've drilled down so I'm pretty sure I know the right question to ask - let's see how I've done.

I have a single-page app using Knockout 3.4.0. A main page, with a number of attached user controls. I have a tab set defined on the main page, and it works fine:

```
    <div class="newportal documentsView" id="documentsView">
        <div class="tabs">
            <ul data-bind="foreach: tabs">
                <li><a data-bind="attr: { href: '#tab-' + name }, css: { selected: $root.currentTab() == $data }, click: $root.updateTab, text: name"></a></li>
            </ul>
            <!-- ko foreach: tabs -->
            <div class="area" data-bind="attr: { id: 'tab-' + name }, template: { name: template, data: $data.model().viewModel }">
            </div>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have a second set of tabs defined on one of the controls that houses the contents for one of those top tabs.  The code's all but identical to the top one, save for referring to different data:

EDIT - duplicate IDs and tag names altered at suggestion of commenter - no change to format or functionality.

```
        <div class="newportal documentsView" id="bulkDocumentsView">
            Welcome to Bulk Documents
            <div class="tabs">
                <ul data-bind="foreach: bulktabs">
                    <li><a data-bind="attr: { href: '#bulktab-' + name }, css: { selected: $root.currentBulkTab() == $data }, click: $root.updateBulkTab, text: name"></a>
                        <!-- ko if: $root.currentBulkTab() == $data -->
                        (*)
            <!-- /ko -->

                    </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- ko foreach: bulktabs -->
                <!-- ko if: $root.currentBulkTab() == $data -->
                <div class="area" data-bind="attr: { id: 'bulktab-' + name }, template: { name: template, data: $data.model().viewModel }">
                </div>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The "$root.currentBulkTab" ko conditionals are in there so I can confirm that the links are correctly holding the correct selected tag and "highlighting" correctly - they do, and are.

However, the final page is only formatting the top set as tabs, the second set are displaying as an unformatted UI set:

[image]

The functionality is right - showing correct selected page, etc.  If i don't have the second ko conditional around the template section, it displays all three, another thing that I believe should clear once the tab formatting applies properly.

The css file being used is jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css - I can comment the file out and the top tabset mimics the behavior of the second one.

There's clearly some additional link or tag I need to hit to get the data on the sub-page to format properly, but I don't know what it is.  Can you only have one tabset per page, and it needs to be some sort of "sub tabset" of which I'm unaware?

I'm assuming the styles should cascade through (The word "cascade" is part of their title) but do they somehow function differently?

Thoughts?

Comment: You have duplicate ids, and that could be the cause of only formatting the first set of tabs.  Any css you have for `#documentsView` will only be applied to the first element with that id.  Also, you may run into the same problem for the elements in your `foreach: bulkTabs` loop, in the case that the `attr: { id: 'tab-' + name }` is the same as it is in the top's `foreach: tabs` loop

Comment: I've updated the second one to bulkDocuments view with no change. I've updated the second tag to { id: 'bulktab-' + name }, also with no change. I updated the top one to { href: '#bulktab-' + name } just as a check - no soap. Functionality remains, formatting does not change

Answer (score 0):

Yes, jQuery UI allows nested tabs.  My guess is you are calling the jquery UI `.tabs()` command on a selected limited to the outer/top tab set only.

Here, I'm calling it on the class selector:

```
$(".tabs").tabs();
```

I've removed all external CSS and hard-coded the HTML since your `<ul>`s and `<li>`s are showing, since I don't think this is a Knockout issue. You can see the nested tabs and that they are clickable and hide non-selected content.

```js
$(".tabs").tabs();
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <div class="tabs">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#tab-1" class="selected">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab-2" class="">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab-3" class="">3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tab-1">
      <div>
        1 - Top level tab content
        <div class="tabs">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#bulktab-1" class="selected">1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#bulktab-2" class="">2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#bulktab-3" class="">3</a></li>
          </ul>
          <div id="bulktab-1">
            1 - Second level tab content
          </div>
          <div id="bulktab-2">
            2 - Second level tab content
          </div>
          <div id="bulktab-3">
            3 - Second level tab content
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="tab-2">
      <div>
        2 - Top level tab content
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="tab-3">
      <div>
        3 - Top level tab content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't scroll out enough, and if I had, you'd all have probably seen the problem.

The second snippet above is (was) contained within a conditional that checks that the dropdown has a selected value.

```
                <!-- ko if: selectedSupplier() -->
    <div class="newportal relative">
        <div class="newportal documentsView" id="bulkDocumentsView">
            Welcome to Bulk Documents
            <div class="tabs">
                <ul data-bind="foreach: bulktabs">
                    <li><a data-bind="attr: { href: '#bulktab-' + name }, css: { selected: $root.currentBulkTab() == $data }, click: $root.updateBulkTab, text: name"></a>
                     <!-- ko if: $root.currentBulkTab() == $data -->
                        (*)
                        <!-- /ko -->

                    </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- ko foreach: bulktabs -->
                <!-- ko if: $root.currentBulkTab() == $data -->
                <div class="area" data-bind="attr: { id: 'bulktab-' + name }, template: { name: template, data: $data.model().viewModel }">
                </div>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
                <!-- /ko -->
```

It would appear to me that being within such a conditional blocks the stylesheet from properly seeing the code - I'm probably not saying that properly.

I move the conditional to only block the template underneath (and removing my test conditionals):

```
    <div class="newportal relative">
        <div class="newportal documentsView" id="bulkDocumentsView">
            Welcome to Bulk Documents
            <div class="tabs">
                <ul data-bind="foreach: bulktabs">
                    <li><a data-bind="attr: { href: '#bulktab-' + name }, css: { selected: $root.currentBulkTab() == $data }, click: $root.updateBulkTab, text: name"></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- ko if: selectedSupplier() -->
                <!-- ko foreach: bulktabs -->
                <div class="area" data-bind="attr: { id: 'bulktab-' + name }, template: { name: template, data: $data.model().viewModel }">
                </div>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And bingo.

[image]

Now that means it's going to be smarter for me to put a separate dropdown on each sub-page, but that'll solve a problem I was having on how to pass the selected values down to it anyway, so, you know, two birds.

98% finding the problem, and 2% fixing it.